# Django Pillow install on Amazon EC2

Tags: django, amazon-ec2, python-imaging-library, libjpeg

Currently I am on a mac os x os and trying to push a django app to amazon ec2 webserver (a linux one). Everytime I include Pillow==4.0.0 in requirements.txt I get the following error when I go to eb deploy:

```
 The headers or library files could not be found for jpeg,
  a required dependency when compiling Pillow from source.
```

However I already sshed into my instanse and ran

```
 sudo dnf install libtiff-devel libjpeg-devel libzip-devel freetype-devel lcms2-devel libwebp-devel tcl-devel tk-devel
```

Which had no effect.

Answer (score 2):

For anyone with this issue look at :

```
https://www.cocept.io/blog/development/using-pillow-on-amazon-elastic-beanstalk/
```

Basically your going to create a `01-flask.config` file that will hold what packages you need to install in linux server (using yum) to install your dependencies in `requirements.txt`

to install pillow on amazon ec2 i put

```
packages:
    yum:
        libjpeg-turbo-devel: []
        libpng-devel: []
```

in the `01-flask.config` as it has the jpeg codecs

Comment: For people just wanting the dependencies: `$ sudo yum install  libjpeg-turbo-devel libpng-devel`